# Rendering does not work when trying to use a library

Tags: android

I am trying to use a library called HolographLibrary.
I put the jar file under lib,and I wrote the dependencies like that.

```
dependencies{
compile files('libs/HoloGraphLibrary-master.jar')
```

but When I try to use the library in a xml file , it says
the following class could not be found,
-com.echo.holographlibray.LineGraph(Fix build Path , edit xml file , create class).

Here is my xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.echo.holographlibrary.LineGraph
android:id="@+id/holo_graph_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Is this "HoloGraphLibrary-master.jar" file in your libs folder ?

Comment: @sunilsunny yes it is.

Comment: did you put the jar in right gredle file?

Comment: @DevendraSingh I put in the build.gradle file

Comment: is the `build.gredle` file exists  in app folder? there are two another `build.gredle` files.

Comment: @DevendraSingh yes it is. I use other libraries there and it works but this one doesnt.

Comment: try this  "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" and remove this "compile files('libs/HoloGraphLibrary-master.jar')" . Clean and sync the project

Comment: @sunilsunny i did it. but it doesnt work in my situation

Comment: What was the issue ?.. Try re-downloading the jar file ..May be it is corrupted.